# Inside temperature reading 13 degrees lower than actual outside temperature - what could be the problem?

Tags: nissan, temperature, sentra

I have a 2006 Nissan Sentra. Its inside temp is reading 58 degrees when it is actually 71 degrees outside. What could be the problem?

Also, I just changed the thermostat today.

Comment: What do you mean by "inside temp"?

Comment: Do you mean the outside temp display on the dashboard?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm. Either temp sender calibration is off a little bit or it's colder inside the car than it is outside the car.

Remember when you are in Defrost or Defog modes on your Heating Ventilation Air Conditioning (HVAC) the Air Conditioning is turned on automatically to help remove water vapor from the air, and keep the Windows clear. This will cool the car's interior too.

I do have to ask. I didn't know the Sentra included an inside temperature read out. I believe the automatic HVAC option lets you set your desired inside temperature to set your comfort levels. Is that what you are talking about?

Is it possible for you to take a photo of the display inside you car and then edit your question to add a link to the image?

Comment: im pretty sure they're confusing where the aat sensor gets it's reading from. or the question should read exterior temp reads x and my weather station reads y. some cars do have vent temperature sensors but the data isn't visible outside of the hvac computer.

Comment: Wow, Well that question has changed considerably since I wrote my answer for it.  I sure would like to hear from @Josette